# How to end code if "If" Condition is not met

Tags: python-2.7

In my code I have two weights that need to equal 1.0. If not I need a print statement saying the conditions are not met and it wont continue to run the rest of the code.

My issue is that if conditions are met, it runs the code forever and it is supposed to continue with the rest of the code. And if they are not met I just want to make sure that it will not run the rest of my code and stop altogether. Two issues that need to be addressed I guess.

No numpy allowed pls.

```
weight_1 = 0.5
weight_2 = 0.5

while True:
    if ((weight_1 + weight_2) == 1.0):
        print ("Weights are appropriate")
    else:
        print("Error! Weights limits not appropriate!")
        break;
```

Comment: Put a `return` statement after the `print`. But your code is not very elegant to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys 
 weight_1 = 0.5
 weight_2 = 0.2

if ((weight_1 + weight_2) == 1.0):
        print ("Weights are appropriate")

else:
        print("Error! Weights limits not appropriate!")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.